# Windows Phone - DateTime type of Database throws exception

Tags: datetime, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce, windows-phone

I have a DateTime field for storing the creation date of my entity:

```
    private DateTime _creationDate;

    [Column(DbType = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get { return _creationDate; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _creationDate, value); }
    }
```

This will throw the follwoing exception:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException:
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Overflow while converting to 'datetime'.
  Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeError=25933
  StackTrace:
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet.SetValues(SEPREPAREMODE mode, SqlCeUpdatableRecord record)
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet.InternalInsert(Boolean fMoveTo, Object sender, SqlCeUpdatableRecord record)
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet.Insert(SqlCeUpdatableRecord record, DbInsertOptions options)
    at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DoResultSetInsert(TrackedObject item)
    at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item)
    at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
    at PinboardApp1.App..ctor()
  InnerException:
```

I have also tried using *DbType="DATETIME2"*.

Is this a general issue or is there a work-around?

Comment: Well what value are you sending?

Comment: Datetime on SQL Compact and SQL Server only accepts values between year 1753 & 9999

Comment: you have problem with C# code or sql side? you connect your windwos phone with sql server?

Comment: My field is initialized in the constructor with the current Date: *_creationDate = new DateTime();*